# Missing lib file when building QwtPlot3d with Qt 5.1.1

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5.1

I am trying to build [qwtplot3d library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwtplot3d/) with Qt 5.1.1. Everything seems to be build fine and it generated .dll file but I couldn't find .lib file must be generated. I have pulled source code from trunk but it seems it didn't build with Qt5(may be it built with Qt4). May be this is a QT5 porting problem but I couldn't any solution.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the preprocessor definitions defined in qwt3d_global.h. Here is my some solutions to overcome this problem.

replace below line, Q_WS_WIN is no longer used by QT5 so that replace it with Q_OS_WIN preprocessor definition.

```
#if defined(Q_WS_WIN) 
with
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
```

and then,
Add following code line to export the missing library, current definitions is not being used but they are still in this file, I don't know why.

```
#if defined(QWT3D_EXPORT_DLL)
#  define QWT3D_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define QWT3D_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

By the way, don't forget to add QWT3D_EXPORT_DLL definitions into preprocessor definitions in VS settings, or define it somewhere else

or just add QWT3D_DLL, QWT3D_MAKEDLL definitions into preprocessor definitions, or define them at somewhere else; otherwise it can't generate lib file at all.